# Linux Virtual Networking Bridge

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, bridge, linux-kvm

Host machine:

- Ubuntu minimal with just SSH
- KVM as hypervisor
- Two separate NICs

  - enp5s0
  - enp7s6

Guest:

- pfSense OR Untangle OR Sophos (I've tried all three just for reassurance)

After installing Ubuntu minimal and KVM on my host I've configured `/etc/networking/interfaces` as such:

```
auto lo enp5s0 br0
iface lo inet loopback
iface enp5s0 inet manual
iface br0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.100
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 192.168.1.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
     broadcast 192.168.1.255
     bridge_ports enp5s0
```

This static address is updated to reflect the correct settings according to the router/firewall software I install next.

I create my firewall/router guest with two network interfaces - the host device enp7s6 (passed through to the guest and connected to the wan) and br0 (to connect to the host and other VMs).

[Picture of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqO65.png)

I'm able to get a link and address from my modem on enp7s6 as well as internet traffic - no problems there.

I'm able to set up a DHCP server on the guest and other VMs as well as other physical machines (not the Ubuntu host) can get IP addresses - no problems there.

During this entire process and even after, I'm able to SSH from the LAN side to the hypervisor in order to accomplish all of this; however, port forwarding to the hypervisor (to SSH from the WAN side) isn't possible regardless of which firewall/router I try.

I've also noticed that I'm unable to see any recognition of the host (Ubuntu/hypervisor) in any router software - no recognition of a lease or active client.

Just for testing, I'd set the network configuration for br0 up as DHCP to see if the hypervisor would receive an IP from the router - it doesn't. I tried `# dhclient br0` and it just hangs.

I suspect there is some type of virtual interface that I'm unfamiliar with or some kind of configuration that I don't know.

For clarification's sake: My goal is to configure the network in such a way that the host (Ubuntu/hypervisor) is visible to the router which is installed as a guest.

If my configuration appears to be correct and there is something I am doing wrong with my router/firewall software advise and I'll ask on the appropriate forum. Thanks!